# What is the use of super with arguments?

Tags: python, super

`super()` is a function in python used to acces members of a super class but sometimes it takes some arguments, what does does super with arguments do.

If either takes a class, a class and object or two classes other than no argument

What is the purpose of each? Where are they use

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two-argument form is the standard. The object specifies *which* MRO to search, the type specifies where to start looking in the MRO.

Almost always, you want to use the type of the current class, and you want to use the method's `self` argument as the object, so Python is set up to "default" to these values if you pass no arguments. (In Python 2, you were *required* to provide arguments explicitly; Python 3 added the feature of inferring the commonly used arguments when none were given.)

If you pass *one* argument, only the current type is used; no object is implied, and you get an "unbound" instance of `super`. (Uses cases for such an object are rare.)